# Overlapping Div despite with float

Tags: singularitygs

I am trying to do this.
[image: wireframe]

with this sass.

```
#map {
    @include grid-span(8,1);
}

#form {
    @include grid-span(4,9);
}

#info {
    @include grid-span(8,1);
}
```

The problem is the #form and #map div are overlapping.

This is on 12 columns grid.

I know I need the clear and float. Tried many combinations. I've read the similar questions' link on floats and isolation. Still don't get it. Please enlighten.

Comment: Please provide a code example on http://sassmeister.com/

Comment: http://sassmeister.com/gist/36ac770f71ccab14b236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking is for Clears, as you noted.

In Singularity for the `float`, `isolation`, and `calc` output styles, all items attached to the grid are floated `left`, unless the span ends on the last column in a row, in which case it is floated `right`. That means, given your example, `#map` and `#info` are floated left and `#form` is floated right.

Clears can seem tricky, but I find that just saying them aloud helps. `clear: left` or "Clear Left" is "Clear everything floated left". `clear: right` or "Clear right" is "Clear everything floated right". `clear: both` or "Clear Both" is "Clear everything floated both left and right". `clear: none` or "Clear None" is "Clear nothing, be it floated left or right". In this case, "everything" is "all sibling elements that come before me".

With this in mind, what you are looking to do is clear `#map`. `#map` is floated `left`, so you would add `clear: left` to your `#info` item. This will clear `#map` but won't add in the margin you're looking for. Fortunately, percentages, even when used for top/bottom, are still based on the browser's `width`, so if you want the same gutter between `#info` and `#main` that you have between both of them and `#form`, all you need to do is add `margin-top: gutter-span();` to `#info`.

In the end, this is the code you'd wind up having:

```
#map {
  @include grid-span(8,1);
}

#form {
  @include grid-span(4,9);
}

#info {
  @include grid-span(8,1);
  clear: left;
  margin-top: gutter-span();
}
```

Here's a fork of your SassMesiter, [showing it in action](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9d2afc029450cc41200e)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this. Thank you for Singularity.gs. I love it because the syntax is readable.

Comment: Side tracking: While your solution solved the problem in context, when I put in my project, the #form is pushed down, flushing with #info. Can you point me the direction I should look into for troubleshooting? p/s I am not able to reproduce my issue in sassmeister. i.e. it's on Drupal Omega 4 theme.